# Map a java.sql.Type to multiple varchar/varying fields

Tags: java, jpa

I have an embedded class in my java/hibernate application that I want to map to 3 database fields as a Type (so that I can use it as a CustomVersionType).  At the moment the error I'm getting is

> org.hibernate.MappingException: property mapping has wrong number of
>   columns: com.imsproto.model.RuleOfEngagementCI.contextIdentifier type:
>   com.imsproto.usertypes.ContextualisedIdentifierVersionType

to be honest I'm not sure that a mapping would fix the problem but I would like to try.  As far as I can see the scenarios where one extends the dialect and adds a custom mapping are for where there is actually an unmapped type in the database (examples I have seen may be out of date but include UUID & json fields).  In this case what I want to do is map some a composite type against 3 fields.  This is the table sturcture...

```
 //Standard hibernate code
@Embeddable
public class TestType implements Serializable
{

@Transient
public Class getUnderlyingClass() { return TestType.class;}

@Column(name="`id1`", nullable=false, length = 100)
private java.lang.String id1 = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

@Column(name="`id2`", nullable=false, length = 100)
private java.lang.String id2;

@Column(name="`id3`", nullable=false, length = 100)

public java.lang.String getId1()    {
    return id1;
}

public void setId1(java.lang.String value)    {
    this.id1= value;
}

public int compareTo(TestType b) {
    if (Id1.equals(b.Id1)) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}

}

@Entity
@Table (name="`hib_test`")
public class HibernateTest implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; 

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name="seq-gen", sequenceName="seq", allocationSize=1)
@GeneratedValue (strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="seq-gen")
@Column(name="`id`", nullable=false)
private Long id;

@Column(name="`NAME`", length=100)
private String name;

@Type(type = "com.proto.usertypes.TestType")
@Version
@Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name="id1", column=@Column(name="`id1_in_testtype`"))
    ,@AttributeOverride(name="id2", column=@Column(name="`id2_in_testtype`"))
    ,@AttributeOverride(name="id3", column=@Column(name="`id3_in_testtype`"))
    })
private TestType testType;

public TestType getTestType()    {
        return testType;
    }
    ...
}
```

What I want to do is map TestType as a Type so that it treats it as a composite datatype.  This type when added would be accessible through the Java.sql.Types enum. Is this possible or am I grasping at straws ?